# React typescript onClick event typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm making a React + typescript project. And i have number button which looks like this:

```
<button className="num" type='button' value={'1'} onClick={inputHandler}>1</button>
```

You can notice that i also have onClick={inputHandler} on that button:

```
  const inputHandler = (event: any) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   setInput(prev => prev.replace('_', event.target.value));}
```

This handler taking a value prop of button and setting it in to the input. So i am stucked on typing event for this handler. Every type i am defining returns:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

If i typing it as "any", obviously it working. But i need to define exact type for it. Help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I'll type the event argument as a generic Event.

Inside the function I'll make a variable that receives the actual HTML element and then cast the type using the `as` keyword, because the argument "event" itself is not a HTML element, it is more advisable to make a variable with the target.

```
  const inputHandler = (event: Event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const element = event.target as HTMLButtonElement;
    setInput(prev => prev.replace('_', element.value));
  }
```

Comment: Typescript was yelling at me with `Event` so I had to change it to `MouseEvent`. But your suggestion to cast event target with typescript `as` was just awesome. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>` as type, like so:

```
const inputHandler = (
  event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>
) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  //...
};
```

[image: Edit angry-fast-upe615]